# I have Error Called Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregate

I have some issues with MongoDB aggregate in node.js
Error: Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators

This is my code

```
let find_result =  await Users.aggregate([
  { $sample: { size: 10 } },
  { $group: { _id: '$_id'} },
  { $project: {
    _id : {
      $nin: arr2
    }
  }},
  { $unwind: '$_id' }
])
```

This code is to output randomly without duplication except for yourself and the person you choose (arr2 contains your _id and the _id of the person you choose)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the comma before unwind.

```
let find_result =  await Users.aggregate([
            { $sample: { size: 10 } }
            ,{ $group: { _id: '$_id'} },
            { $project: {
                "_id" : {
                  $nin: arr2
                }
              }
            },
            { $unwind: '$_id' },
          ])
```

Comment: oh.. man.. Big Mistake..